# Live validation instead of on button click validation

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to use live page validation instead of the VALID or INVALID message showing after pressing submit, my code validates an email address and when the submit is clicked the input displays below followed by valid or invalid, if valid it will be in green and if invalid it is in red. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Email Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form onSubmit='validate(); return false;'>
<p>Enter an email address:</p>
<input id='email' placeholder="example@example.com" size="21">
<button type='submit' id='validate'>Submit</button>
</form>
<br/>
<h2 id='result'></h2>
<script>
function validateEmail(email) { 
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
function validate(){
$("#result").text("");
var email = $("#email").val();
if (validateEmail(email)) {
$("#result").text(email + " is valid");
$("#result").css("color", "green");
} else {
$("#result").text(email + " is not valid");
$("#result").css("color", "red");
}
return false;
}
$("form").bind("submit", validate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onChange() event of your email input to call your validate() method instead of your submit button or you can call on both events...

Example:

```
<input id='email' placeholder="example@example.com" size="21" onchange="validate()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use `Jquery validate` plugin

```
$(function() {

// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

// Specify the validation rules
rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    lastname: "required",
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    agree: "required"
},

// Specify the validation error messages
messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter your first name",
    lastname: "Please enter your last name",
    password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    agree: "Please accept our policy"
},

submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
});

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/sm29s4xe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

bind the validate event to the text-box's focus out.

example:

> $("#email").focusout(function () {
>
> validate();
>
> });

this way it will run through the regex right after you un-selected the email textbox, aka when you filled it in, instead of when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve that issue inside your javascript code:

```
$("#email").on('input', function() {
  // do your validation here
});
```

The function then automatically called each time you enter or remove a character in the input field. If you only need to validate after the user pressed RETURN or the focus is no longer on the input field, use:

```
$("#email").on('change', function() {
  // do your validation here
});
```

Comment: I have been trying to use this in my code but I do not know where to put it, can you give me an indication as to where it needs to go?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you this is way is cleaner - use as inspiration:

```
function validateEmailField() ...

function validateAllFields() {
  return validateEmailField() && validateUsernameField();
}

// make sure submit on enter key or alike is triggering validate
// you might use a 'validateAll' function here
$('form').on('submit', validateAllFields);

// validate field on leaving it
$('form').on('blur', '#email', validateEmailField);
```

While at it: You may also use HTML5-WebForms (with Polyfill for old browsers) to use a really simple form validation technique. Have a look at at this page (validation is further down) ... [Form Validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)